# Filtering by using a varchar column in sql

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, amazon-athena, datediff

I have a table which has a date but stored as a `varchar` datatype column:

| my_date | metric_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-12 | CLS |
| 2021-09-12 | FID |

I want to keep only 30 days back using this column.

I tried using `cast(my_date as date)` in the `where` clause, but it is not working.

Can you assist?

My code is in ANSI SQL.

Comment: datediff is not an ANSI SQL function.

Comment: Alter the column data type to date instead of having it as varchar, and life will become easier.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using Amazon- Athena db.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast your column as a date.  That would suggest syntax such as:

```
where cast(my_date as date) >= current_date - interval '30' day
```

That said, date/time functions are very database specific, so the exact syntax varies by database.

Comment: the cast(my_date as date) is not working at all in a where statement. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: @ChrissieM. I fixed answer a little bit, it should work now.